# Spring MVC-JQuery-AJAX Updating Single row from table using Ajax and Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Below Code is giving me 400-BAD REQUEST error for AJAX CALL.

In below code there is a table where i am Populating all the Student records like
rollnumber , firstname , last name and address with edit and Delete button
right now i am working on EDIT button.

Requirement :- Click on Edit Button , it should make table attributes available for editing for that particular row , after editing click on update and it should get updated into database and should show there again is Non-Editable Field in table.
Below is my Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatetemp",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = 
{"application/json"})  
SQLException{
@ResponseBody
  public boolean edit(@RequestParam("rollnumber") int rollnumber,
                           @RequestParam("firstname") String firstname,
                           @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
                           @RequestParam("address") String address)
                                                    throws SQLException{
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setRollnumber(rollnumber);
        s.setFirstname(firstname);
        s.setSurname(surname);
        s.setAddress(address);
        if(this.studentService.update(s)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Below is my Jquery and Ajax call Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click','#editlink',function(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(2)"); 
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(3)"); 
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
    tdName.html("<input type='text' class='firstname' 
value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdPhone.html("<input type='text' class='lastname' 
value='"+tdPhone.html()+"'/>");
    tdEmail.html("<input type='text' class='address' 
value='"+tdEmail.html()+"'/>");
    $("#editlink").prop('disabled',true);
});

$(document).on('click','#updatelink',function(){
    var rollnumber = $(this).parent().siblings('.rollnumber').text();
    var firstname;
    var surname;
    var address;
$(this).parent().siblings("td.firstname").
find("input.firstname").each(function() {
        firstname = (this.value);
    });
    $(this).parent().siblings("td.lastname").
find("input.lastname").each(function() {
        surname = (this.value);
    });
    $(this).parent().siblings("td.address").
find("input.address").each(function() {
        address = (this.value);
    });

    var studentjson = { rollnumber: rollnumber, firstname: firstname, 
surname: surname,address: address };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/updatetemp',
        data: studentjson,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) { 
            console.loge(response);
            if(response == true){
                $(this).parent().siblings("td.firstname").html("<td 
 class='firstname'>"+firstname+"</td>");
                $(this).parent().siblings("td.lastname").html("<td 
class='lastname'>"+surname+"</td>");
                $(this).parent().siblings("td.address").html("<td 
class='address'>"+address+"</td>");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I think the main problem is with my AJAX call.... Please Help me. Its been two days i am trying hard... I am newbie!

Comment: Did you try it without setting the `contentType` option?

Comment: Also you are saying the method `produces = 
{"application/json"}`, but you are returning a boolean ......

Comment: I really dont know what should i do ?? should i remove contentType and produces ? and then try?

Comment: Try them one at a time and see if anything changes.

Comment: I removed Content Type from ajax call now its giving 500 Internal Error

Comment: Try to log the inputs as soon as you get into the method.  Try to track down what exactly is causing the 500.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has @RequestParam whereas you are passing studentjson as body in the call. To pass something as request param then send data as

```
"'http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/updatetemp"+ "?rollnumber=" + rollnumber + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&surname=" + surname  + "&address=" + address
```

Instead I would request you to change your controller's edit method to @RequestBody POJOClass pojoClass and all fields rollnumber, firstname, surname, address should be property in the POJOClass